# Is there a way two express middleware can share a single variable declared at the top of the javascript file. I'm working with two middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, commonjs

I need one middleware to set the value whereas the next middleware reads from the value as its parameter and not through the req, or res objects.
This is a snippet of the main javascript file

```
...
var testData = "initial Data"

app.use("/",function(req,res,next){
  testData = "Changed data"
  next()
},// I need this next middleware to read the testData directly as a parameter
function(testData){

  return function(req,res,next){
    console.log(testData)
    next()
  }
})
...
```

I tried declaring the variable as a global variable same as you would do in a normal ECMAScript. Unfortunately the testData was reading as undefined and causing some errors.

**Do note** that I don't want to use the res.locals variables because that would mean that I would first have to pass in the req,res,next objects as in a typical express middleware.

Comment: What if multiple users access the API at the same time? Is it correct that user A getd data from user B?

Comment: @jabaa, it isn't correct to say so, they would be using different browsers.

Comment: But you're using one server. This is server-side code. The same code with the same memory and the same machine is used for all users.